# ASPNet.Core HostingEnvironment for Integration Tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In building the Integration tests for my ASPNet.Core web app, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing,
I am coming across an issue. The Startup is run when I run the app and the configuration is read and contains all the information in my `apsettings.json` file.
Now, when I run the integration test as shown below. the Startup is run but the configuration is different. Why would that happen and how do I make sure it reads 
the one for the app itself?

```
[TestFixture]
class HSMControllerTests
{
    private readonly TestServer _server;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HSMControllerTests()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>());
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public async global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task GET_PingHSM_ShouldSucceedAsync()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("HSM/PingHSM");
        Assert.NotNull(response);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkObjectResult>(response);
    }
}
```

I am getting the exception `Missing configuration section ServiceConfig.`

This is how the WebHost is built in `Program.cs` in my app:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .UseKestrel(o => o.AddServerHeader = false)
       .Build();
```

Could the difference in how it is built in the Test code be the problem?

**Modified ControllerTest constructor:**

```
public HSMControllerTests()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.GetFullPath(@"../../../../HSM.WebApi.IntegrationTests"))
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    _server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>());
    _client = _server.CreateClient();
}
```

Now, how to inject the new Configuration into the Startup? Our Startup is defined like this:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
        : base(typeof(Startup), configuration, environment)
{
}
```

**modification based on last post by @poke**

```
_server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder => new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.GetFullPath(@"../../../../HSM.WebApi.IntegrationTests"))
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    )
    .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

**Got it working, somewhat...**

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Path.GetFullPath(@"../../../../HSM.WebApi.IntegrationTests"))
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var Configuration = config.Build();

_server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
    .UseStartup<Startup>());
_client = _server.CreateClient();
```

But now, the HostingEnvironment is set to the directory of the Tests app vs. the directory of the Web app and it attempts to read to `appsettings.json` file from there in the HomeController constructor, here:

```
public HSMController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
}
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace. *“Missing configuration section ServiceConfig”* is not an exception, and we have no idea where that’s coming from.

Comment: *“the Startup is run but the configuration is different”* – different *how*? And how exactly are you verifying that?

Comment: @poke, as I step into Startup(), the configuration parameter is evaled. It is different when running from the Test project vs. the Web app project. In the Test project, there is only a single provider whereas in the Web app, there are 5 providers.

Comment: @poke, I cannot post the stack trace due to proprietary units, but it looks like it's coming from here: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

Comment: I'm able to build a configuration object with the correct data, how do I inject it into the builder? Se modified code above...

Comment: Is the appsettings.json available in the IntegrationTest project ?

Comment: @vasiloreshenski, Yes it is now, but I'd rather use the one from the Web app.

Comment: You can use `IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration`, i.e. `new WebHostBuilder().ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder => configBuilder.SetBasePath(…).AddJsonFile(…)).UseStartup<Startup>())`

Comment: See modification, still the configuration in Startup is not correct and exception still occurs.

Comment: That’s not what I was saying you have to do. You should **not** create a new configuration builder.

Comment: @poke, post and answer about copying the `appsettings.json` in the integration testing project and set to `Copy Always` as that is the answer to getting it to work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the `appsettings.json` file to the integration tests project folder and set it to Copy Always and it works correctly.

Answer (score 7):

## ASP .Net Core 2.0

Copy you appsettings.json files to your integration test and set them to copy always.

Create MyTestServer Class as it will likely be reused in many tests.  Remember that CreateDefaultBuilder will automatically load your appsettings and use environment.

```
  public class ApiTestServer : TestServer
  {
    public ApiTestServer() : base(WebHostBuilder())
    { }

    private static IWebHostBuilder WebHostBuilder() =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseEnvironment("Local")
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
          options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001);
        });
  }
```

Then in your test

```
public SettingsTests()
{
  TestServer = new ApiTestServer();
  HttpClient = TestServer.CreateClient();
}
```

Comment: how to run the same tests on the different environments? 
for example:
"local" and "dev" 

if I'm using that line - " .UseEnvironment("Local")" the environment will always "Local". 

Do you know how to use generic environment or pass it somehow to code ?